# No me funciona el constructor por defecto (Base de datos Objeto Relacional)

Tags: base-de-datos, oracle-11g, object, oracle-sqldeveloper

Me gustaria saber si vosotros veis el error, es que no entiendo porque no puedo insertar registros con el constructor por defecto, solo por el constructor que he definido

```
    create or replace type MiembroEscolar force as object
(
    codigo INTEGER,
    dni VARCHAR2(10),
    nombre VARCHAR2(30),
    apellidos VARCHAR2(30),
    sexo VARCHAR2(1),
    fecha_nac DATE
)not final;
/

    create or replace type Profesor force under MiembroEscolar
    (
        especialidad VARCHAR2(20),
        antiguedad INTEGER,

    constructor function Profesor 
    (
        codigo INTEGER,
        nombre VARCHAR2,
        pr_apellido VARCHAR2,
        seg_apellido VARCHAR2,
        especialidad VARCHAR2
    )return self as result,

    member function getNombreCompleto return varchar2
);
```

/

```
create or replace type body Profesor as

    constructor function Profesor 
    (
        codigo INTEGER,
        nombre VARCHAR2,
        pr_apellido VARCHAR2,
        seg_apellido VARCHAR2,
        especialidad VARCHAR2
    )return self as result 

    is

        begin
            self.codigo := codigo;
            self.nombre := nombre;
            self.apellidos := pr_apellido || ' ' || seg_apellido;
            self.especialidad := especialidad;
        return;
        end;

    member function getNombreCompleto return varchar2

    is
        begin
        return self.apellidos ||' '|| self.nombre;
        end;
end;
```

/

```
create table Profesorado of Profesor;
/

    insert into Profesorado values 
    (
/* El primer registro no me funciona, me salta Error SQL: ORA-00947: not enough values*/
        Profesor(2,'51083099F','MARIA LUISA','FABRE BERDUN','F','31/03/1975','TECNOLOGIA',4),
/* Si ejecuto solo este registro me funciona correctamente */
        Profesor(3,'JAVIER','JIMENEZ','HERNANDO','LENGUA')
    );
```

Un saludo y gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vale, lo he solucionado separando cada insert

```
insert into Profesorado values 
(

    Profesor(3,'JAVIER','JIMENEZ','HERNANDO','LENGUA')
);
insert into Profesorado values 
(

    Profesor(2,'51083099F','MARIA LUISA','FABRE BERDUN','F','31/03/1975','TECNOLOGIA',4)
);
```

Así me funciona los dos constructores, pensaba que se podia hacer en un mismo insert utilizar los diferentes constructores, pero se ve que no :s